# Show/hide toastbar on sending service call & and after receiving response

Tags: codenameone

I want a toastbar that should display a message to the user before calling a service and hides it after getting the service response.How can I do this??I mean i dont need the expire time to hide it .It should be hidden only after getting the service response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ToastBar.Status` and show/dispose it manually:

```
    ToastBar.Status s = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
    s.setIcon(FontImage.createMaterial(icon, stl, 4));
    s.setMessage(msg);
    s.setExpires(-1);
    s.show();
```

When you are done with this just call `s.clear()`.